# Scala Infix Type Puzzle

Tags: scala, types, infix-operator

I had understood that prefix and infix were equivalent. Why then do the following give different type answers?

```
3.*(5)                                        //> res50: Double = 15.0
3*5                                           //> res51: Int(15) = 15
```

Comment: Much ambiguity – So arbitrary…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd guess what's happening here has nothing to do with infix vs. prefix.

It's almost certainly tokenizing `3.*(5)` as `3.`, `*`, `(`, `5`, `)`. The `3.` is equivalent to `3.0` -- a floating point number. So, it's parsed as an infix expression: `3.0`, `*`, `5` (with redundant parens around the `5`).

Since `3.0` is floating point, the result is floating point as well.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I now see that (3).*(5) demonstrates what I wanted.